# FS readFileSync causing problems in windows service

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, windows-services, fs

I have a small express script that was making an api. I then used node services to make it a service and set it up to run after mongoDb kicked off. Worked like a charm however I had to add HTTPS support which requires me to read the keys using fs.readFileSync. Now the process just ends after starting. If I run the file it works fine so I think it has to do with the window service trying to access a users file. Has anyone run into this before? Below is both the code for the file creating the API and the code used to make the service.

```
    https
    .createServer(
        {
            key: fs.readFileSync("certs/server.com.key"),
            cert: fs.readFileSync("certs/server.com.crt"),
            passphrase: "redacted",
        },
        app
    )
    .listen(port, function () {
        console.log(
            `Example app listening on port ${port}! Go to https://localhost:${port}/api`
        );
    });
```

```
var Service = require("node-windows").Service;

var svc = new Service({
    name: "FavoritesAPI1.1",
    description:
        "This starts the express server for the favorites API and connects to MongoDB.",
    script: "C:\\Users\\srv-qlik\\Desktop\\FavoritesAPI\\index.js",
    nodeOptions: ["--harmony", "--max_old_space_size=4096"],
});

svc.on("install", function () {
    svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

Comment: What is the error message? My first guess would be that you run into a "`ENOENT`" error. Try to set the "Curent Working Directory" of your application to `C:\\Users\\srv-qlik\\Desktop\\FavoritesAPI`. Where is your "certs" folder located?

Comment: Can’t see the error message on the service. The certs folder is in the same folder as the index.JS file that is on the desktop of the user.

Comment: @Marc Thank you, I changed the directories of the files to be the full path and it is working.

Comment: im glad that i can help you. Note: for services you should see error/logs in the Windows Event Log, not 100% sure how it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the fs file paths to the full paths and it seem to be working.